# Have problem with boolean alternation in react,

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

console always returns "true" meaning except first button click

```
        import React, {useState} from 'react'
        function App() {
            let [itemState, setLike] = React.useState( [
                      { id:1, likeIt:false, }
                    ])
                    function addToWish(id){
                      setLike( itemState.map(item=> {
                        if(item.id === id){
                          item.likeIt = !item.likeIt 
                        }
                        return itemState
                      })) 
                    }
                     console.log(itemState)
                   return(<button onClick={()=> addToWish()}></button>);}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to update the state in your case would be to use a functional update and also in the callback passed to `map` you should return the `item`.

```
function addToWish(id) {
  setLike((prevState) =>
    prevState.map((item) =>
      item.id === id ? { ...item, likeIt: !item.likeIt } : item
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: tried to edit due to you're reccomendation suggestion, but problem is staying, just now it returns only false

Comment: @Bogdan9817 I think you're logging at the wrong place. state is updated asynchronously. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately?rq=1).